# Mobile Background Images Pixelated

Tags: css

Re this site:

http://www.jenniferharper-deacon.com/

I have added background images using the following css:

```
#pl_areauzza45k .pl-area-wrap {
    background-image: url("http://www.jenniferharper-deacon.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/WHEAT-FIELD.jpg");
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

However they seem to be pixelated on my phone. Any help on how to solve this would be very appreciates.

Comment: I have just walked into this... My images are 300dpi and half the pixel size but still pixelated.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the image is getting shrunk.

Try this:

```
#pl_areauzza45k .pl-area-wrap {
    background-image: url("http://www.jenniferharper-deacon.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/WHEAT-FIELD.jpg");
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```